# Recover/reupload messages deleted by fetchmail

Tags: email, data-recovery, imap, fetchmail

I used fetchmail to access my Hotmail/Outlook mailbox. It downloaded every message inside Inbox, but now that folder is empty at the server. Now I see that fetchmail deletes messages by default:

> -k | --keep  :  Keep retrieved messages on the remote mailserver. Normally, messages are deleted from the folder on the
>   mailserver after they have been retrieved. Specifying the keep option
>   causes retrieved messages to remain in your folder on the mailserver

I expected to find them in the Deleted folder or the Archive folder at the server but they are not there. Is there a way to find them (maybe something like a Imap/Deleted folder) or a way to reupload them?

Comment: Do you still have your local copies? (Wherever `fetchmail` ended up putting them.)

Comment: Yes, I used fetchmail + maildrop and they are in the local mailbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using Thunderbird:

1. Install [Thunderbird](https://www.thunderbird.net/)
2. Link Hotmail account to Thunderbird using the same IMAP settings as in fetchmail
3. In Thunderbird install [ImportExportTools](https://addons.thunderbird.net/thunderbird/addon/importexporttools) extension
4. Create new folder in Local Folders, right click on the new folder, select ImportExportTools and import mbox file, select the user's mailbox file (e.g. /var/mail/myusername)
5. Drag the new local folder into the linked Hotmail account in Thunderbird, wait until all messages are uploaded back to the server